# How to use “left” and “strpos” to get the left part of a string with an expression?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a table in QGIS with full names and I want to parse into first name(s) and last name. I’ve created the columns and am using Expression Builder to do this. Here's what I'm trying and it's not working. `left( "name",strpos( "name", " ") )` with name being the full name. I've tried just putting in `strpos( "name", " ")` to see if things are working and nothing shows up. I click on Update Selected and nothing changes. I've tried putting the whole expression in `last_name = "name",strpos( "name", " ") )` and no luck. QGIS on Mac OSX. PostGIS[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fall into this trap a lot.

In expression builder, `"name"` is the value of field called name, and `'name'` is the string "name". You just need to use single quotes around any text strings.

Try

```
left( "name",strpos( "name", ' ') )
```

Comment: Thank you. I swore I tried that combination and it didn't work. But this did. And it works as i wanted it to.